# How can I update a value in a .ts file in Angular from a HTML value?

Tags: angular, paypal, mean-stack, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the ngx-paypal package from node to implement paypal payments in my angular app. Inside my TS file, I can see where the value for the price of a product is set, and it's currently set to a hard-coded value of '9.99'. I want to make this price change based on the value stored in my MongoDB, which I've been able to successfully display in my HTML page, but haven't been able to pass this value into the PayPal API. I'm new to using Angular/MEAN stack, and I wasn't sure how to go about grabbing the value and passing it into the API. Thanks!

```
//.ts file snippit
initConfig() {
this.payPalConfig = {
  currency: 'EUR',
  clientId: 'sb',
  createOrderOnClient: data =>
    <ICreateOrderRequest>{
      intent: 'CAPTURE',
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency_code: 'EUR',
            value: '9.99',
            breakdown: {
              item_total: {
                currency_code: 'EUR',
                value: '9.99'
              }
            }
          },


//html file snippit
.
.
.
 <h2 class="animated flipInX delay-2s" id="price" >{{ spotsData.price }}</h2>
.
.
.
```

the spotsData.price is the value that I want to pass into the .ts file rather than 9.99. Thank you and let me know if there is anything I need to clarify!

edit: added where I fetch spotsData

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(this.startMap, 2000);

    let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.selectId = id;

    this.spotsData = [];

    this._chosenSpotService.getSpots(this.selectId).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(this.spotsData);
      this.spotsData = data;
    });
```

Error after moving initconfig

```
Uncaught Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status: 400 (Corr ID: ddc5504012afb)
```

Comment: Please share the code where you're fetching the `sportsData.price` value from the API that exposes your MongoDB Data.

Comment: Just added it @SiddAjmera

Comment: And where are you calling `initConfig` ? You should ideally be calling it inside the `subscribe` block.

Comment: I was calling it immediately outside of the subscribe block, I can move it up though! This is my first angular app so I'm always learning.

Comment: Can you share data you getting from db?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `initConfig();` right outside the `subscribe` will call it immediately(synchronously) rather than waiting for the `subscribe` block to run. The `subscribe` block will run asynchronously, only once the data is retrieved from the API.

You'll get the data inside the `subscribe` block. So ideally you should be calling `initConfig` after you've set `this.spotsData` to `data`.

Give this a try:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(this.startMap, 2000);
  let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.selectId = id;
  this.spotsData = [];

  this._chosenSpotService.getSpots(this.selectId).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(this.spotsData);
    this.spotsData = data;
    initConfig();
  });
}
```

And then in your `initConfig()` method:

```
initConfig() {
  this.payPalConfig = {
    currency: 'EUR',
    clientId: 'sb',
    createOrderOnClient: data => <ICreateOrderRequest> {
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: 'EUR',
            value: this.spotsData.price,
            breakdown: {
              item_total: {
                currency_code: 'EUR',
                value: this.spotsData.price
              }
            }
          },
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error 400, after the paypal window launches, it just crashes

Comment: Do you get any error? If you do, please share it in the Question.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/535) it's an intermittent issue with the sandbox environment itself and not an issue with your code. You might want to try again in some time. Hopefully it should work by then.

Comment: In that thread it seems like the OP's problem was resolved within a couple days, I also haven't been able to find any issue with the code besides that, but have been running into that issue anytime I try to pass values in via this.spotsData.price, for ~1-2 months.

Comment: I've never used stackblitz, I can send you anything that would be useful though